# Need to Delete Folder older than 30 days but exclude some

Tags: perl

Need a favour to delete folders older than 30 days in a given directory, but not folders which is mentioned in text file or user specified (which may be older than 30 days, but we should not delete)

```
set DIRPATH=%1
set MAXDAYS=30 
forfiles -p %DIRPATH% -m *.* -d -%MAXDAYS% -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
forfiles -p %DIRPATH% -d -%MAXDAYS% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

This code deletes any folders older than 30 days.  I want to exclude some directories.  How do I accomplish that?

Comment: This is not Perl code.

Comment: `FORFILES /S /D -30 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"`

Comment: Hi serenesat,  you can try it in perl, but i have tried it in bat

Comment: What do you mean by "given by user"? how? and how does the content of the text file look like?

Comment: i will give some folder names in text file

Comment: that folder names should not be deleted, even if it is older than 30 days in that directory

Comment: I tried to clarify your question but might have guessed wrong.  Please review the edit and correct it if I broke something.

Comment: So there is no user input but a text file only for specifying folders to exclude??

Comment: yes, read text file and exclude the content (which is folder name) delete all others

Comment: tripleee you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If whatever I understood is correct, You should proceed like this:

1. Read the file with directory names and store it into data-structure (in my case it is hash).
2. Read the directory and filter out the folders from there.
3. Iterate over the directory and skip the folders which are in text file and remove other folders which are more than 30 days old.

Overall This can be summarized in a Perl script as below:

**Caution: comment `rmdir $folder;` during testing to save yourself from   unintensional data loss.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

#pass your file containing directory-name through command-line
my $file_with_dir=$ARGV[0];
my %dirs;

#open your file to check directories which shouldn't be removed
open my $fh, '<', $file_with_dir or die "unable to open file $file_with_dir: $!\n";
while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    $dirs{$_}=1;
}
close($fh);

#read the folders from directory
my $dir=<your folder name here>;
opendir(my $dh,$dir) or die "unable to open DIR $dir: $!\n";
my @folders=grep{ !/^\./ && -d $_} readdir $dh;
closedir($dh);

#get today's date and time 
my $curr_time=localtime;

foreach my $folder( @folders )
{
    next if $dirs{$folder}; #skip if folder-name is in file you provided
    my $stat=stat($folder);
    my $creation_time=localtime($stat->ctime) if($stat);
    #calculate difference in days
    my $diff_days=int(($curr_time-$creation_time)->days);
    if($diff_days > 30){
     print "$folder is more than $diff_days days old deleting...\n";
     #delete the folder use with caution comment it when you are testing
     rmdir $folder or warn "unable to remove dir $folder: $!\n"; 
    }
}
```

**Update:**

[`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is generally used to filter out the elements from the list. I am filtering out the elements which satisfies two criterias

1. `!/^\./` This means any element in list which shouldn't start with `.`, as directory may contain `.` and `..`.
2. [`-d`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) is used to check whether the item is directory or not(in your case it is folder).

Comment: Hi Arunesh Singh, seems to be okay, could you explain me this line my @folders=grep{ !/^\./ && -d $_} readdir $dh; closedir($dh);

Comment: Check the update and retag it to `perl` if this worked for you.

Comment: code is executing but its not deleting older elements, instead of my $dir=<your folder name here>; i have given like this my $dir="D:/SDI/TestResults/mainline/mainline"; even single quotes also not working

Comment: calling script like below, C:\Users\myname>D:\perl\DeleteFolder.pl "C:\Users\310136595\Documents\FolderName.txt"

Comment: Are you using windows or unix?Escape the slashes well. Check whether it is reading folder from directory by printing.

Comment: Keep your script in `D:/SDI/TestResults/mainline/mainline` or you need to give absolute path in `rmdir` also.

Comment: i am getting this error Can't locate object method "days" via package "Time::Piece" at C:\DeleteFolderLessthanXdays.pl line 28.